# Calculate diff time for combinations of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, combinations, common-table-expression, cross-join

I need to calculate the time it takes for trucks to go from one station to another. I want to select any origin and destination in my dataset and calculate the average time it took for all trucks.

This is how the data could look like this:

| Truck Number | Origin | Destination | Departure | Arrival |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | 01-01-2022 | 05-01-2022 |
| 1 | B | C | 10-01-2022 | 15-01-2022 |
| 1 | C | D | 16-01-2022 | 20-01-2022 |
| 1 | D | E | 20-01-2022 | 22-01-2022 |
| 2 | A | B | 15-01-2022 | 25-01-2022 |

We would need to get all the combinations from origins to destinations for the next X destination for a particular origin. It would be great if it could have a variable so we can set that we want the following X destinations. In the example it would be x=3 since we calculate the different between A and B C D but not AE:

| Truck Number | Origin | Destination | Transit Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | 5 days |
| 1 | A | C | 15 days |
| 1 | A | D | 20 days |
| 1 | B | C | 5 days |
| 1 | B | D | 10 days |
| 1 | B | E | 12 days |
| 1 | C | D | 4 days |
| 1 | C | E | 6 days |
| 2 | A | B | 10 days |

Main question would be how to calculate all combinations for x stops in the future.

Comment: this would call for a recursive cte.

Comment: thanks! recursive cte + cross joins maybe? way above my sql level

Comment: What if the truck route is not consistent, perhaps sometimes traveling A>C>B>D or A>E>C>D? Are there any return trips that would create a loop such as A>B>C>A? If history shows additional routes A>W>X>Y>Z>D, do you want to average that in or only calculate the shortest route based on averages for individual legs? The latter case would be a form of the [Shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), where the edges are weighted by the average time between stations.

Comment: the average could be calculated later. the sequence would be specified by the truck and departure date order. the main problem would be generating the X combinations: A-B, A-C, A-D. It is possible to have A-A but it would be fine since we would have different dates and we would calculate the difference between the days. how to get the second table? thats the question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
      origin, destination, avg(datediff(day, Departure, Arrival))
from data
GROUP BY origin, destination
```

Put truck number in the select and remove the aggregation if you want to keep this at the level of the trucks.

I proposed the above, as you might want to get to the average time from A->B then B->C, as components, and then A->C as rollup.

you can do that with lead/lag to look for the next origin to be equal to the prior destination...

Comment: This would not help me generating all combinations for X number of stops

Answer (score 0):

I made a few assumptions. First, the routes only go in one direction, ie, A->B->C->D. Second, truck numbers are unique and don't skip numbers. Third, origins and destinations are always alphabetical.

So, step one was to create a table with all of the possible origin/destination permutations. That was done with the Cross Join and a While loop to iterate through the trucks/origins/destinations. As the same time, I calculated the transit time between each permutation.

Next would be the X number of stops. That's where the Row_Number comes in. Partitioned and ordered the way it is, you can simply select everything less than or equal to your X number of stops (@Destinations). If you set @Destinations to a number greater than what's in the ResultsTable, it will just return the whole table. If you set it to 0 or NULL, it returns nothing.

Finally, in your expected results, you have two different calculations for Transit Time. A>B is 5 days but only if you count both Departure and Arrival. B>C is 5 days but only if you don't count both. I counted both. If you only want to count one, take out the + 1 in the Transit calculation.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5mp1IHdn?hide=4)

```
DECLARE @Destinations INT = 3
DECLARE @Truck INT = 0
DECLARE @maxTruck INT
DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE 
           (rn INT, TruckNumber INT, Origin CHAR, Destination CHAR, Transit VARCHAR(10));

SELECT @maxTruck = MAX(TruckNumber)
  FROM trips;

WHILE @Truck <= @maxTruck
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @ResultTable (rn, TruckNumber, Origin, Destination, Transit)
         SELECT 
           DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.TruckNumber, t1.origin ORDER BY t1.origin, t2.Destination) AS rn,
                    t1.TruckNumber,
                    t1.Origin, 
                    t2.Destination, 
                    DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.departure, t2.Arrival )+ 1 AS Transit
               FROM trips t1
         CROSS JOIN trips t2
              WHERE t2.destination > t1.origin
                AND t1.TruckNumber = @Truck and t2.TruckNumber = @Truck
   SET @Truck = @Truck + 1   
   END

SELECT --rn, 
       TruckNumber,
       Origin,
       Destination,
       CONCAT(Transit, ' Days') Transit
  FROM @ResultTable
 WHERE rn <= @Destinations
 ORDER BY TruckNumber,Origin,Destination
```

@Destinations = 3 returns:

| TruckNumber | Origin | Destination | Transit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | 5 Days |
| 1 | A | C | 15 Days |
| 1 | A | D | 20 Days |
| 1 | B | C | 6 Days |
| 1 | B | D | 11 Days |
| 1 | B | E | 13 Days |
| 1 | C | D | 5 Days |
| 1 | C | E | 7 Days |
| 1 | D | E | 3 Days |
| 2 | A | B | 11 Days |

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive cte as the following:

```
declare @x_lvl int,
        @number_of_origins int;
set @x_lvl = 3;
set @number_of_origins = 3;

with cte as
(
  select row_number() over (partition by TruckNumber order by departure) rn,
         TruckNumber, Origin, 
         Destination, departure, 
         arrival, 1 as rec_level 
  from tbl
  union all 
  select C.rn,
         T.TruckNumber, C.Origin, 
         T.destination, C.departure, 
         T.arrival, C.rec_level +1
  from tbl T join cte C
  on T.TruckNumber = C.TruckNumber and
     T.Origin = C.Destination and
     T.departure > C.departure
  where C.rec_level < 3
)
select TruckNumber, 
       Origin, 
       Destination,
       Concat(Datediff(day,departure, Arrival) + 1, ' days') Transit_Time
from cte
where rn <= @number_of_origins
order by TruckNumber, Origin, Arrival
```

`@x_lvl` is used to limit the number of retrieved destinations per origin.

`@number_of_origins` is to limit the number of origins per truck.

[See a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LxX5rviI)

Answer (score 0):

This may be as simple as a self join that pairs any trip with any same or later trip for the same truck. This would select all combinations of origins and destinations for each truck. Adding a limit requires the addition of a CTE to assign a windowed row number, that can then be used later to limit the hops. A date diff, group by, and average calculation will then yield the desired results.

```
DECLARE @Limit INT = 3

;WITH NumberedTrips AS (
    SELECT
        T.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.TruckNumber ORDER BY T.Departure) AS LegNum
    FROM Trips T
)
SELECT
    T1.Origin, T2.Destination,
    AVG(0e0 + DATEDIFF(day, T1.Departure, T2.Arrival)) AS TransitTime
FROM NumberedTrips T1
JOIN NumberedTrips T2
    ON T2.TruckNumber = T1.TruckNumber
    AND T2.LegNum BETWEEN T1.LegNum AND T1.LegNum + @Limit - 1
GROUP BY T1.Origin, T2.Destination
ORDER BY T1.Origin, T2.Destination
```

Sample results:

| Origin | Destination | TransitTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 7 |
| A | C | 14 |
| A | D | 19 |
| B | C | 5 |
| B | D | 10 |
| B | E | 12 |
| C | D | 4 |
| C | E | 6 |
| D | E | 2 |

The above is slightly different from your posted expected results, which were not consistent in the date difference calculation. Your first 3 rows added +1 to the actual date difference (inclusive day counting perhaps?), but the remaining rows did not.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z28VkPZF) for a working demo.